# How do i get the number of specific child elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the Html..

```
<figure>
    <img class="hover_active" src="http://placehold.it/360x480&text=image+1" alt="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/360x480&text=image+2" alt="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/360x480&text=image+3" alt="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/360x480&text=image+4" alt="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/360x480&text=image+5" alt="">

    <figcaption>
        <h5>Product Name</h5>
        <p>Rs. <span class="original_price">2,000</span></p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

What i need to do is get count of number of child elements inside `figure` element and not select the `figcaption` element which also happens to be the child of `figure`, so that i can further create a loop and pass on the 'number of image items' as a variable in JavaScript. Could someone please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName), try:

```
var len = document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[0].getElementsByTagName("img").length;

//document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[0] --> get first 'figure' tag
//.getElementsByTagName("img") --> get all 'img' elements inside first 'figure' tag
//.length --> get the length of 'img' elements
```

Demo:: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqjdg/)

if you are using jQuery, do:

```
var imgLength = $(".product_grid_list").find("figure > img").length;
alert(imgLength);
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/4N2XA/)

Comment: Appreciate your help Sudhir, i modified your statement like this `$(function() 
  {
      var imageCount = $('product_grid_list').find('figure')[0].getElementsByTagName('img').length;
      
      alert(imageCount);
  }
);` but the alert is not working. here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wP3QQ/1/), can you please tell me what is wrong

Comment: @Anuj see updated answer, you are missing selector in $('product_grid_list'), if its a class use $('.product_grid_list'), if its id use $('#product_grid_list')

Comment: @Anuj 'imgLength' is the total number of img elements, its a numeric value..!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use < IE8 and old opera browsers, then you can easily use just

```
document.querySelectorAll('figure img').length
```

P.S. safe version

```
var frag = document.querySelectorAll('figure img'),
           counter = (frag === null) ? 0 : frag.length;
```

Comment: well yeah.. i dont have a slightest clue about the second statement :P